# Snake body will not add new block

Tags: python, vector, atom-editor

I was following a tutorial and I can't seem to get my code to add a block to the end of the snake. It still runs, but not the way I want it to. It doesn't add new blocks. I called the class and function, but it still doesn't work. I think it may be a problem with the move_snake and add_block function, but I am not sure.

```
class SNAKE:
    def __init__(self):
        self.body = [Vector2(5,10),Vector2(6,10),Vector2(7,10)]
        self.direction = Vector2(1,0)
        self.New_block = False

    def draw_snake(self):
        for block in self.body:
            x_pos = int(block.x * cell_size)
            y_pos = int(block.y * cell_size)
            block_rect = pygame.Rect(x_pos,y_pos,cell_size,cell_size)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,pygame.Color('brown'),block_rect)

    def move_snake(self):
        if self.New_block == True:
            body_copy = self.body[:]
            body_copy.insert(0,body_copy[0] + self.direction)
            self.body = body_copy[:]
        else:
            body_copy = self.body[:-1]
            body_copy.insert(0,body_copy[0] + self.direction)
            self.body = body_copy[:]

    def add_block(self):
        self.New_block = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never call `add_block()`. Perhaps you should do so when you eat an apple?

Comment: I call the function in my main class, I am not sure how to show you another line of code on here I'm not overstack savvy, but I called in another class called main where I defined collisions. Then the snake head and apple are equal then the apple moves to a random spot and the snake gets extra block.

Comment: I understand what you mean now I did forget the "()" it works the way it's supposed to now thank you.